# When ufw enabled, FTP client stuck on: 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, ftp, ufw

when I try to connect to FTP server as the following commands in debian while **ufw** is enabled

I got connected successfully

but I can't list the content of directories with the command **ls** , because it stuck on **150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.**

But when I disable the **ufw** I got it working perfectly.

```
ftp ServerName.com
Connected to ServerName.com.
220 Microsoft FTP Service
331 Password required
Password:
230 User logged in.
Remote system type is Windows_NT.
ftp> ls
200 EPRT command successful.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
```

the **ufw** config as the following

```
ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
20/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
20/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Am I doing any thing wrong !! or what I have to add to the **ufw** to allow my ftp client to work as expected ?

Comment: before `ls` add `pass` to activate passive ftp connection.

Comment: thanks @RomeoNinov , work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have open already port 20 you can make ftp to use passive connection by enter command `pass` after you authenticate.